# Trying to parse XML directly from a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking at this XML:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.xml

I thought I could parse out the 'ethcty' and 'cnt' items from the list, using the code below, but I'm actually getting nothing at all.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)

for _id in root.findall('_id'):
    rank = _id.find('ethcty').text
    name = _id.get('cnt')
    print(name, rank)
```

I am following the examples from the URL below.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `response` element there's a `row` element, so your `for` loop should be in `root[0]` instead of `root`

Here's an example from your snippet, hope it helps you understand the issue

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('rows.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for _id in root[0].findall('row'):
    rank = _id.find('ethcty').text
    name = _id.find('cnt').text
    print(name, rank)
```

Also, `findall` should be the name of the node you want

As for loading directly from the url you should use the `urllib` as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with urlopen('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.xml') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for _id in root[0].findall('row'):
        rank = _id.find('ethcty').text
        name = _id.find('cnt').text
        print(name, rank)
```

I edited the latter code because I forgot about the loading from the URL part of your question, i'm sorry about that

Comment: I'm glad to help!